# How did math borrow 'factor' as in commercial agent?

Tags: terminology, math-history

I was researching [factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_(agent)) as factor intermediaries, and its etymology [on Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=factor).

> [factor (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/factor#etymonline_v_1068)
>
> early 15c., "commercial agent, deputy, one who buys or sells for another,"
>   from Middle French *facteur* "agent, representative" (Old French factor, faitor "doer, author, creator"),
>   from Latin *factor* "doer, maker, performer," in Medieval Latin, "agent," agent noun from past participle stem of *facere* "to do" (from PIE root **dhe-* "to set, put").
>   In commerce, especially "a commission merchant." **Mathematical sense is from 1670s.** Sense of "circumstance producing a result" is attested by 1816, from the mathematical sense.

1. What "mathematical sense" "from 1670s" does Etymonline mean? ['Factor '](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor) is too polysemous!

> - A term in [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication)
> - [Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor), an integer which evenly divides a number without leaving a remainder
> - [Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization), the decomposition of an object into a product of other objects
> - [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), the process of breaking down a composite number into smaller non-trivial divisors
> - A [coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient), a multiplicative factor in an expression, usually a number
> - The act of forming a [factor group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) or [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) in abstract algebra
> - A [von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra), with a trivial center
> - [Factor (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_(graph_theory)), a spanning sub graph
> - Any finite contiguous sub sequence of a [word in group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(group_theory))

2. Why did mathematicians in 1670s borrowed "factor"? Commission merchants in 1670s probably had to multiply and divide, but they also had to add and subtract too.

Comment: This belongs on the [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s an extension of the sense ‘maker’ of Latin *factor*: a factor of a number is in a sense one of its ‘makers’, one of its constituent parts. This is the earliest mathematical sense noted in the OED Third Edition, which has this 1658 citation from George Atwell, [*The faithfull surveyour discovering divers errours in land measuring, and showing how to measure all manner of ground, and to plot it, and to prove the shutting by the chain onely ...*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A26162.0001.001?view=toc):

> Because there are four figures in the Fractions of the two Factours; therfore there are also four in the product.

Answer (score 0):

Not a "why" answer, just some references. According to the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" pages](http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html):

> FACTOR (noun). Fibonacci (1202) used *factus ex multiplicatione* (Smith vol. 2, page 105).
>
> Factor appears in English in 1673 in *Elements of Algebra* by John Kersey: "The Quantities given to be multiplied one by the other are called Factors."
>
> FACTOR (verb) appears in English in 1848 in *Algebra* by J. Ray: "The principal use of factoring, is to shorten the work, and simplify the results of algebraic operations." Factorize (spelled "factorise") is found in 1886 in *Algebra* by G. Chrystal [OED].

The Kersey reference correlates with the 1670s timeframe noted by Etymonline, and may at least hint at what was meant by "mathematical sense".